# SQL CONSTRAINT UNIQUE can't insert more data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table where I insert some data. The problem is that I can't go higher than about 53000 rows, then when the table industry_updated is about to reach 53000 rows it goes back down to about 52000 rows. I still have plenty of space left in the db, I don't have any schedulers or tasks on this table. There is an index on industry_url.
What could it be? Thanks.

**Command to insert the data**:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO industry_updated (skills,weight,industry,industry_url) VALUES ('$skills','$weight','$industry','$industry_url')
      
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      
      skills = '" . $skills . "' ,
      weight = '" . $weight . "' ,
      industry = '" . $industry . "' ,
      industry_url = '" . $industry_url . "' 
  
      ";
```

**Table**:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE industry_updated (
skills VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
weight INT(10) NOT NULL,
industry VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
industry_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT UC_industry_updated UNIQUE (skills,industry_url)
)";
```

Comment: Where are you getting your row counts from - are you COUNTing or getting from information_schema

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can see the count in the DB, for example today: Showing rows 0 - 29 (52163 total, Query took 0.0010 seconds.) a few days ago I had 52851 rows.

Comment: Mysql won't delete rows by itself so someone or some code is.

Comment: Or you have a trigger on the table.

Comment: That's what I thought and this is why I've created a similar new table to make sure that I didn't have any tasks assigned to it. I've checked with select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS and there aren't any triggers.

Answer (score 0):

So I've used `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT skills) FROM weighted_skills_industry;` to count the rows and there are no issues as the Skills are increasing as expected.

What goes down though is the number of rows on the screen in PhpMyAdmin i.e. So today Showing rows 0 - 29 (52231 total, Query took 0.0006 seconds.) for 12414 skills after running the code above, while yesterday it said Showing rows 0 - 29 (54566 total, Query took 0.0006 seconds.) for 12404 skills. Not sure why the Showing rows message on the screen varies so much from one day to another with less rows today than yesterday but more skills.